# How to change marker label color of react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I am using [@react-google-maps/api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/api) library. I've integrated google map but I am facing marker label color, I tried very hard but didn't find any solution. Could someone please help me with how to resolve this issue.

```
import {
  Marker,
} from "@react-google-maps/api";

{markers.map(({ id, name, position }) => (
        <Marker
          key={id}
          position={position}
          onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(id)}
          label={`${id}`}
        >
          {activeMarker === id ? (
            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}>
              <div>{name}</div>
            </InfoWindow>
          ) : null}
        </Marker>
      ))}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerLabel

Comment: Any one please solve this issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:
 `` label: {text: `${id}`, color: "blue"} ``

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code :

```
label={{text:`${id}`,color:'#fff'}}
```

Add this label attribute in Marker tag

Answer (score 0):

We can add to the MarkerLabel object key & value className

```
label={{text:`${id}`, className:'marker-label'}}
```

And then add all the necessary  styles for this class